# Dynamically add and sort items in tableview python

Tags: python, pyqt

Reading data in from a simple dict d={key:['desc',dateadded]} 
Goal is to add data into table view and sort by date in the list.  Cannot get any data to add when trying to put table on main window.

The issue lies with how I am placing the table on the main window. I have a working widget with table and am now trying to combine the two files. Currently the application crashes.  Dont want you to write the code but a nudge in the right direction would be a big help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'display.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QMainWindow, QApplication)
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        self.setmydata()
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(296, 478)
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        MainWindow.setAnimated(False)
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtGui.QTabWidget.Rounded)

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 261, 391))
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableView.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)
        self.tableView.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.tableView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableView.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.tableView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableView"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 10, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 296, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def setmydata(self):
        d={"12345678":["do some stuff here that needs to be in a large cell to wrap text","1"],"12343378":["do stuff","1"]}


        self.data = {}

        keys=d.keys()
        self.data['col1']=keys
        self.data['col2']=[]
        for key in keys:
               self.data['col2'].append(d[key][0])
        horHeaders = []

        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.data.keys())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add New", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save", None))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
frame = Ui_MainWindow()
#frame.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the code I found line

```
self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
```

needed to be QTableWidget rather than a View. This allows for me to set values and so on.